# Время выполнения - ноль?

Tags: python, python-3.x, время, модули

В пытаясь составить таблицу времени выполнения разных реализаций одного алгоритма столкнулся с неожиданной работой моей программы по замеру времи выполнения.
Вот код:

```
# Function Description 
# https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/maximizing-xor/problem?utm_campaign=challenge-recommendation&utm_medium=email&utm_source=24-hour-campaign
# maximizingXor has the following parameter(s):
#     l: an integer, the lower bound, inclusive
#     r: an integer, the upper bound, inclusive
# Return the maximal value of the xor operations for all permutations of the integers from l to r inclusive
# Sample Input 
# 10
# 15
# Sample Output 0
# 7

from itertools import combinations, starmap
from operator import xor

# itertools solution.
def maximizingXor_i(l, r):
    return max(starmap(xor, combinations(range(l,r+1),2)))

# itertools solution with unpacking to list
def maximizingXor_li(l, r):
    return max(list(starmap(xor, combinations(range(l,r+1),2))))

# cycle solution with List Comprehensions
def maximizingXor_lc(l, r):
    return max([i^j for i in range(l, r+1) for j in range(i+1, r+1)])

# cycle solution without List Comprehensions
def maximizingXor_c(l, r):
    _=0
    for i in range(l, r+1):
        for j in range(i+1, r+1):
            _= max(i^j, _)
    return  _

import time
import pprint
times = [(10,15), 
        (100,150), 
        (10000,15000), 
         ]
funcs = [maximizingXor_i, maximizingXor_li, maximizingXor_lc, maximizingXor_c]

rez = {}
for f in funcs:
    rez[f.__name__] = {}
    for l,r in times:
        ts = time.time()
        void=f(l,r)
        te = time.time()
        rez[f.__name__][l] = (te-ts)*10000000
pprint.pprint(rez)
```

и вот результат:

```
{'maximizingXor_c': {10: 0.0, 100: 0.0, 10000: 62401347.160339355},
 'maximizingXor_i': {10: 0.0, 100: 0.0, 10000: 23212623.596191406},
 'maximizingXor_lc': {10: 0.0, 100: 0.0, 10000: 31498529.91104126},
 'maximizingXor_li': {10: 0.0, 100: 0.0, 10000: 31516406.536102295}}
```

ребята, ну что со мной опять не так? ((
время выполнения равно нулю... уже умножил на 10 млн и те же яйца...
в отладчике `te==ts` при малых `l,r`.

Comment: Попробуйте вместо `time` использовать `from timeit import default_timer`: `ts = default_timer()` и `te = default_timer()`. А также попробуйте использовать time.perf_counter или time.process_time

Comment: @gil9red  -  заработало!! (С)простоквашино.
Однако - вопрос-то остался.
Че за ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать `from timeit import default_timer`:

```
...

from timeit import default_timer

rez = {}
for f in funcs:
    rez[f.__name__] = {}
    for l,r in times:
        ts = default_timer()
        void=f(l,r)
        te = default_timer()
        rez[f.__name__][l] = (te-ts)*10000000
pprint.pprint(rez)
```

---

Просто, [time.time()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/time.html#time.time), не очень точный, т.к. возвращает время в секундах:

> Return the time in seconds since the epoch as a floating point number. Note that even though the time is always returned as a
> floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better
> precision than 1 second. While this function normally returns
> non-decreasing values, it can return a lower value than a previous
> call if the system clock has been set back between the two calls.

Пример:

```
import time
t = time.time()
a = 1 + 2
print('{:.10f}'.format(time.time() - t))      # 0.0000000000

from timeit import default_timer
t = default_timer()
a = 1 + 2
print('{:.10f}'.format(default_timer() - t))  # 0.0000005692
```

Comment: тогда чего стоят все статьи про декоратор типа @timeit, где везде приводят примеры с использованием именно `time.time()`  а не `timeit.default_timer()`?
Благодарю!

Comment: @VasylKolomiets мерять с точностью меньще секунды затруднительно. Лучше увеличить нагрузку в измеряемом участке

Comment: @AndrioSkur - ну тогда почему для `timeit.default_timer()` это менее затруднительно? Похоже на винде и на линуксах время идет с разной детализацией )))

Comment: дык в том то и проблема что `timeit.default_timer()` не очень точное время. То есть абсолютно одинаковые по времени запуски могут показать разный результат в `default_timer`

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, в большинстве случаев точности `time.time()` хватает, например при работает с файловой системой (считывание файла, сохранение), работе по сети (POST, GET)

Comment: @AndrioSkur, а какой таймер лучше использовать? В описании к default_timer написано что с версии 3.3 тот использует time.perf_counter

Comment: `time.time` . Просто нужно нагрузку увеличить. То есть не один вызов функции, а тищ 5 например